# Minecraft Server Wrapper Detecting Logon

Tags: bash, shell, wrapper, minecraft

I'm writing a basic Minecraft server wrapper written in bash, and I need to detect when someone logs on. I have no idea how to do this, so I've come to you. There is a message in `server.log` like this:

```
{date} [INFO] {username}[{ip}] logged in with entity id 514 at ([world] -26.5, 64.0, -80.5).
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a tool more appropriate for the job than Bash, like a server plugin or mod.

Not only will it be easier to accomplish, but you'll also be able to expand functionality beyond detecting logon if you so wish. Some popular server modifications supporting plugins include [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org/) or [CanaryMod](http://www.canarymod.net/).

Comment: mind sharing what you used? This is of interest for me to be able to detect user logins/logouts